# Read file system

Tags: android, file

I´m trying to store a png file in the internal memory of the phone, but I am having a lot of problems after try a lot of diferent ways.

I´m using this code:

```
private void storeImage(Bitmap image, String nombre) {
    try {
        File file = new File(nombre+".png");
        file.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
    }  
}
```